# Is there a way for a drop down list to open automatically using an anchor point?

Tags: html, wordpress

In case it matters, I'm using WordPress as my website tool.

Basically this is what I have

```
<a name="title"></a>[expand title="title" trigclass=noarrow] Various text [/expand]
```

The anchor point is linked from a menu. Is there something I can add that when the anchor point is clicked, the drop down menu opens up? Either that, or is there another way for this to happen?

I'm very new to programming and I've tried looking on google but to no avail.

I'd appreciate any and all help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes there is .. you have to use jquery for that to happen...and instead of anchor ,, use a button with onclick EXPAND function..
Learn jquery thoroughly, it would be very helpful for further programming.